# Why are performance metric libraries needed for metric implementations?

Tags: java, performance, metrics, performancecounter, codahale-metrics

I have this primitive doubt. There are many metrics libraries for Java such as http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/getting-started/ How are these different from having primitive data types and doing the metrics ourselves? For example, this  provides a feature called counters which could be used for measurements for counting. But how does this differ from having a local integer variable and incrementing and decrementing it ourselves? This is not just related to this library, but to all the performance metrics libraries out there. Another feature is health check. How does it differ from having a simple boolean variable for the same purpose? Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Just to get a request count you won't need a metrics library.

IMHO the real benefit is in the enhanced functionality, for example the [meters](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/getting-started/#meters) that provides:

> A meter measures the rate of events over time (e.g., “requests per second”). In addition to the mean rate, meters also track 1-, 5-, and 15-minute moving averages.

together with the reporting facilities like [reporting via jmx](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/getting-started/#reporting-via-jmx), which might take considerable time to implement it correctly.

So basically you could do all those things yourself, but why bother to implement it yourself if an existing library can fulfill all your needs.

And, since it is open source, you can always extend it to metrics that the library itself does not support.